# wordpress register post type rewrite rule doesn't work

Tags: post, url-rewriting, custom-post-type

First post type :

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_pressrelease' );

function create_pressrelease() {

register_post_type( 'pressreleases',
    array(
            'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __( 'Press Releases' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'Press Release' )
            ),
    'has_archive' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => 'edit.php?post_type=storefronts',
        'public' => true,
    'map_meta_cap'        => true,
    'menu_position' => 4,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'revisions' ),
    'taxonomies' => array( 'post_tag' ),
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-edit',
    'has_archive' => 'pressreleases',
    'with_front' => false,
    'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'suppliers/%supplier_name%/pressreleases',
            )
    )
    );
}
```

Second post type :

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_whitepaper' );
function create_whitepaper() {
register_post_type( 'whitepapers',
    array(
            'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __( 'White Papers' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'White Paper' )
            ),
    'has_archive' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => 'edit.php?post_type=storefronts',
    'public' => true,
    'map_meta_cap'        => true,
    'menu_position' => 4,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'revisions' ),
    'taxonomies' => array( 'post_tag' ),
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-edit',
    'has_archive' => 'whitepapers',
    'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'suppliers/%supplier_name%/whitepapers',
            )
    )
    );
}
```

I have created above post types two , I am able to get first post type correct pages and coming to 2nd post type, I am getting URL but the loads homepage content, why it is happening is there anything that i m missing to include in this both codes.suggest me i am trying since two days I have tired various methods like **add_rewrite, perma_structure**, need some solution on this

Answer (score 1):

add flush_rewrite_rules( false ); after this register_post_type( 'straws', $args );

Comment: in your case add flush rewrite rule after this function register_post_type( 'whitepapers',....);

Comment: Take a look at: https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/#description

Answer (score 0):

As i can understand you're getting wrong post link it's causing of

'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'suppliers/%supplier_name%/pressreleases',
)

You just need to remove both 'rewrite' parameter and SET your permalink.